# How to click on email, that contain specific text

Tags: java, selenium, junit

Please help to improve my code. I use JUnit and PageObjectPattern.

I need to:

- in area find email that contains String ("Test"), test fails if email not found
- click on this email and find there Text ("Success")

Page:

```
@FindBy(className = "123")
    WebElement area;

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(text(), 'Test')]")
    WebElement email;

public String findText(){
    return area.getText();
}

public void clickEmail(){
    email.click();
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void goTest() {
    home = new Home(driver);
    Assert.assertTrue("Failed", home.findText().contains("Test"));
    home.clickEmail();
    assertTrue(home.getElement().contains("Success"));
}
```

I get an error: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium \[Java\] PageFactory Design : Where do I write my Assertions following Page Object Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017058/selenium-java-pagefactory-design-where-do-i-write-my-assertions-following-pa)

Comment: I improved my code, but that is not I am lookin for.

Comment: @Happyhappy And what do you expect? You already wrote Assertions you are looking for.

Comment: I expect to get right code. Now I get error message org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible