# Tests using Page Factory Design and Page Object Model opens two instances of the browser using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, page-factory

I have a test in Selenium WebDriver with Page Object Model, if I run the following test open two windows in the Chrome browser, first window is empty in a URL line. How I can opening only one with onet.pl URL?
I trying deleting initialize Chrome driver but will have null.exception error.
What am I doing wrong?

```
package Pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class LoginPage {
    private WebDriver driver;
    //private WebDriverWait wait;

    public LoginPage() {
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
    }
    @FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='col-md-12']//form")
    private WebElement loginForm;

    @FindBy(id="username")
    private WebElement loginField;

    @FindBy(id="password")
    private WebElement passwordField;

    @FindBy(xpath="//button[@class='btn btn-multisport-default btn-multisport-large btn-full-width login-button']")
    private WebElement buttonLogin;
    public void open() {
        driver.get("https://onet.pl");
    }
    public void enterLogin() {
        String login = "vadim1234@test.pl";
        loginField.sendKeys(login);
    }
    public void enterPassword() {
        String password = "Benefit!";
        passwordField.sendKeys(password);
    }
    public void login() {

        buttonLogin.click();
    }
}
```

**And test code:**

```
import Pages.Dashboard;
import Pages.LoginPage;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class LogIn {
    @Test
    public void correctLogin() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        LoginPage loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        loginPage.open();
        loginPage.enterLogin();
        loginPage.enterPassword();
        loginPage.login();
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
        Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard(driver);
        dashboard.getLoggedUser();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `test` class as you are passing the reference of the `driver`:

```
LoginPage loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
```

In `LoginPage` class, within the constructor, instead of:

```
public LoginPage() {
    this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
    //wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
}
```

you need to do reuse the instance passed as follows:

```
public LoginPage(WebDriver loginPageDriver) {
    this.driver=loginPageDriver;
}
```

That would solve the issue of 2 browsers getting opened.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium [Java] PageFactory Design : Where do I write my Assertions following Page Object Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017058/selenium-java-pagefactory-design-where-do-i-write-my-assertions-following-pa)

Comment: sure, have a nice day!