# Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.getTitle()" in Page Object Class using Selenium and Page Factory

Tags: java, selenium, nullpointerexception, pageobjects, page-factory

Created base class:

```
public loginpage() {           
    PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
}
```

Then page objects initialized:

```
public String GetTitle() {
    System.out.println("title111");
    return driver.getTitle();
```

Then created test case:

```
@Test
    public void title() {
    String a=   lp.GetTitle();
    System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.getTitle()" because "this.driver" is null
```

Please let me know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To use the same browser created within the *testcase* or in the *Browser Factory* needs to be reused.

So within the [*Page Objects*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001569/where-should-i-define-modal-specific-code-in-selenium-page-object-model-pattern/49002231#49002231) first you need to:

```
public LoginPage(WebDriver loginPageDriver) {
    this.driver=loginPageDriver;
}
```

and then:

```
public String GetTitle() {
    System.out.println("title111");
    return driver.getTitle();
}
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Tests using Page Factory Design and Page Object Model opens two instances of the browser using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63022955/tests-using-page-factory-design-and-page-object-model-opens-two-instances-of-the/63024001#63024001)

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver driver;

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setupMethod() throws InterruptedException 
{
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();//launch chrome
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(50));//Wait for page to be loaded
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(50));//wait for element click and load(global)
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
}


@Test
public void GoogleTitleTest()
{
    String title=driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(title);
}
```

It will work there ,don't declare Webdriver=driver in @AfterMethod as it has been already declared before use in method.